# How to load html elements dynamically based upon input json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ecmascript-6

How to loop through input array of object?

Currently have included only 2 persons information's. But the input is more than 50 persons information and need to loop through all of them.

Sample Code:

```js
const json = [
  {
    _id: "5af5cf0270d455a211200d4c",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$3,507.97",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 24,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Ahmed",
    gender: "male",
    company: "ATW",
    email: "atw@atw.com",
    phone: "+1 98908098",
    address: "661 Terrace Place, Elliott, Ohio, 9927",
    about:
      "Id sint labore sint dolore ex laboris. Ea irure dolor est nulla laboris Lorem sint fugiat laborum officia commodo. Reprehenderit culpa non voluptate ea. Fugiat duis et deserunt ea enim et ipsum nostrud commodo quis quis laborum officia. Elit est anim quis deserunt nulla nostrud ea eiusmod quis adipisicing. Mollit exercitation officia ipsum ea aliqua amet aliqua esse amet minim. Ipsum quis cillum fugiat reprehenderit sit aliquip aute in excepteur dolore fugiat esse non non.\r\n",
    registered: "2014-12-10T07:18:10 +02:00",
    latitude: -84.359436,
    longitude: 156.008804,
    tags: [
      "excepteur",
      "eiusmod",
      "laboris",
      "fugiat",
      "minim",
      "dolor",
      "qui"
    ],
    friends: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Shields Terrell"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Hilary Bruce"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Lorraine Torres"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5af5cf0254f91fa2d555e1ae",
    isActive: false,
    balance: "$2,219.42",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 27,
    eyeColor: "blue",
    name: "Maisa",
    gender: "female",
    company: "INTERFIND",
    email: "aqr@qra.com",
    phone: "+1 9780989080980",
    address: "595 Foster Avenue, Villarreal, Massachusetts, 4604",
    about:
      "Nostrud exercitation ea enim in consequat voluptate sint et laboris laborum elit nisi veniam. Do consectetur magna eiusmod anim nisi id sint consequat. Amet duis proident nisi excepteur. Reprehenderit non amet occaecat deserunt. Duis voluptate non in ex esse sit nostrud esse fugiat laboris fugiat qui reprehenderit.\r\n",
    registered: "2015-07-08T01:24:50 +03:00",
    latitude: -38.471736,
    longitude: -158.491974,
    tags: ["mollit", "minim", "duis", "anim", "aute", "magna", "ut"],
    friends: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Dina Berger"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Carmella Mckinney"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Campbell Wooten"
      }
    ]
  }
];


document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = `${json[0].name}`;
document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML = `${json[0].name}`;
document.getElementById("gender").innerHTML = `${json[0].gender}`;
document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = `${json[0].phone}`;
document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = `${json[0].company}`;
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = `${json[0].address}`;
document.getElementById("about").innerHTML = `${json[0].about}`;
document.getElementById("registered").innerHTML = `${json[0].registered}`;
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Employee's Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h1><span id="name"></span></h1>
    <div class="container" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">

        <div class="flexcontainer">
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="Employee's Picture" id="picture">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Full name: <span id="fullname"></span></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Gender: <span id="gender"></span></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Phone number: <span id="phone"></span></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Company: <span id="company"></span></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Address: <span id="address"></span></h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>About employee:</h3>
            <p><span id="about"></span></p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>Employee was registered in the system: <span id="registered"></span></h3>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="./assets/js/jsonlast.js"></script>



</html>
```

HTML (in my question) page is connected to another page with a table that includes all the names of the persons in the json file. What needed is, whenever clicked on a `name` in the table, it should take me to the `employee.html` (the html page that I included in my question) but with the information of that person.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. Also, the expression `\`${json[0].name}\`` is equivalent to `json[0].name`.

Comment: What do you mean by change the data dynamically?

Comment: Do you intend to loop through the JSON and update the innerHTML?

Comment: @DaltonWhyte yes that's what exactly trying to do

Comment: @rm and happyKoala , I did edit my post . can you check it ?

Comment: Is only one person presented on the page at a time or more than one? I'm asking because it's violation of HTML spec to have more than one DOM element with the same value of "id" attribute, and it would be very problematic to maintain a list depending on ids.

Comment: @rm, yes there are more than 50 person in the json data file.

Comment: It is still hard for me to understand what exactly you need to do with the data. There are answers to your question but, in my opinion, they miss the actual point. Intuitively, I feel like the actual problem is completely unrelated to parsing JSON and is more about presenting the data on the page via DOM mutations. Could you please describe the problem at hand a bit more in detail? How does the user see this information? What do they do with it? Is the whole array of many entries displayed at once on the page or is it some sort of a list-detail split view?

Comment: @rm the html page is connected to another page with a table that includes all the names of the persons in the json file. so what i'm trying to achieve is, whenever I click on a name in the table. it should take me to the employee.html (the html page that I included in my question) but with the information of that person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to loop through the JSON and update the innerHTML of the individual elements. This code below can help you achieve this, note though you have to ensure that your HTML element name must match the name of the JSON property. Ex. this code will not work for:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = `${json[0].picture}`;
```

It should be:

```
document.getElementById("picture").src = `${json[0].picture}`;
```

So before using the solution update your image element to:

```
<img src="" id="picture" />
```

To show multiple persons use this solution, I added two loops, the outer loop will loop through each person record:

Modify your `<ul>...</ul>` to `<ul id="personList">...</ul>`

```js
const json = [
  {
    _id: "5af5cf0270d455a211200d4c",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$3,507.97",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 24,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Ahmed",
    gender: "male",
    company: "ATW",
    email: "atw@atw.com",
    phone: "+1 98908098",
    address: "661 Terrace Place, Elliott, Ohio, 9927",
    about:
      "Id sint labore sint dolore ex laboris. Ea irure dolor est nulla laboris Lorem sint fugiat laborum officia commodo. Reprehenderit culpa non voluptate ea. Fugiat duis et deserunt ea enim et ipsum nostrud commodo quis quis laborum officia. Elit est anim quis deserunt nulla nostrud ea eiusmod quis adipisicing. Mollit exercitation officia ipsum ea aliqua amet aliqua esse amet minim. Ipsum quis cillum fugiat reprehenderit sit aliquip aute in excepteur dolore fugiat esse non non.\r\n",
    registered: "2014-12-10T07:18:10 +02:00",
    latitude: -84.359436,
    longitude: 156.008804,
    tags: [
      "excepteur",
      "eiusmod",
      "laboris",
      "fugiat",
      "minim",
      "dolor",
      "qui"
    ],
    friends: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Shields Terrell"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Hilary Bruce"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Lorraine Torres"
      }
    ]
      },
      {
    _id: "5af5cf0254f91fa2d555e1ae",
    isActive: false,
    balance: "$2,219.42",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 27,
    eyeColor: "blue",
    name: "Maisa",
    gender: "female",
    company: "INTERFIND",
    email: "aqr@qra.com",
    phone: "+1 9780989080980",
    address: "595 Foster Avenue, Villarreal, Massachusetts, 4604",
    about:
      "Nostrud exercitation ea enim in consequat voluptate sint et laboris laborum elit nisi veniam. Do consectetur magna eiusmod anim nisi id sint consequat. Amet duis proident nisi excepteur. Reprehenderit non amet occaecat deserunt. Duis voluptate non in ex esse sit nostrud esse fugiat laboris fugiat qui reprehenderit.\r\n",
    registered: "2015-07-08T01:24:50 +03:00",
    latitude: -38.471736,
    longitude: -158.491974,
    tags: ["mollit", "minim", "duis", "anim", "aute", "magna", "ut"],
    friends: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Dina Berger"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Carmella Mckinney"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Campbell Wooten"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let i = 1;
for(var key in json[i]){
  if(key === "picture"){
    document.getElementById(key).src = json[i][key];
  } else {
    let spanElement = document.getElementById(key);
    if (spanElement){
      spanElement.innerHTML = json[i][key];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div>
        <img src="" alt="Employee's Picture" id="picture">
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
              <h3>Full name: <span id="name"></span></h3>
          </li>
          <li>
              <h3>Gender: <span id="gender"></span></h3>
          </li>
          <li>
              <h3>Phone number: <span id="phone"></span></h3>
          </li>
          <li>
              <h3>Company: <span id="company"></span></h3>
          </li>
          <li>
              <h3>Address: <span id="address"></span></h3>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try it now and will tell you the result

Comment: Sure @AhmedHaiba don't forget to update your image HTML element's id attribute from id="image" to id="picture"

Comment: I tried the following code but I don't think that i'm doing it right :

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = `${json[0].name}`;
document.getElementById("picture").src = `${json[0].picture}`;
document.getElementById("gender").innerHTML = `${json[0].gender}`;

for (var i in json) {
  for (var key in json[i]) {
    if (document.getElementById(key).nodeName.toLowerCase() === "img")
      document.getElementById(key).src = json[i][key];
    else document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = json[i][key];
  }
}

Comment: You do not need this code: document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ${json[0].name}; document.getElementById("picture").src = ${json[0].picture}; document.getElementById("gender").innerHTML = ${json[0].gender};

Comment: Just use the code solution given. Note the use of json[0] only processes one person record

Comment: I tried it again but it doesn't work! maybe I need to change :( const json ) that i'm using in the beginning ?

Comment: This solution will never work. What you are doing is looping the json, over and over replacing the content of the same elements. You will always end up with the content of the last json-element because only then the loop stops.

Comment: Thanks Michel. Can you paste your HTML code as well @AhmedHaiba

Comment: Ok just seen it! Let's fix this.

Comment: @daltonWhyte thank you for your effort but , can you please include html and javascript in your code ? so I can run the snippet and check what i'm doing wrong ? because it still doesn't work for me. oh by the way, i'm trying to show only one person in the page. not all of them, but this html page is connected to a table so whenever I click on a different name in the table it should show his information. that's why I want to loop through all of them

Comment: Sure let me do that @AhmedHaiba

Comment: @DaltonWhyte, I tried it and it works, but it shows all the informations of all the persons in the same page. what I want to achive is to just show the informations of one person in the page. but whenever I choose another person. the page should be updated with the informations of that person I pick. but thank you very much for your time and effort :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181433/discussion-between-dalton-whyte-and-ahmed-haiba).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use EMCAScript 5, you can use this to loop over your `json[0]` object.

```
Object.keys(json[0]).forEach(function(key) {
    var el = document.getElementById(key);
    var isImg = (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img');
    if (isImg) el.src = json[0][key];
    else el.innerHTML = json[0][key];
});
```

Comment: Some values of ID attribute don't match properties of the object in `json` perfectly, for example, `#image` element and `json[0].picture` value. I think this solution goes the other way: it adds more obscurity and promotes bugs. 

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.parse()`, this is a built in function which can turn json format into javascript object. Then you can use this object to change your content. For example:

```js
let JSON_object = "{\"name\": \"willem\", \"fullname\": \"van der Veen\" }"

const parsedObj = JSON.parse(JSON_object)

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = parsedObj.name;
document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML = parsedObj.fullname;
```

```html
<div id="name">random</div>
<div id="fullname">random</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but would it work on all the persons ? because there are more than 50 person in the json file

Comment: As long as they are in the JSON, you can parse them into an JS object using JSON.parse. Then you probably want to use a for loop to iterate over the elements